# return type required for overridden method

Tags: java, extends, return-type

I have the following Class

```
class Stack {
    Node top = null;
    ...
    public Node pop(){ 
        return this.top;
    }
}

class MinStack extends Stack {
    ...
    public Node pop() {
        super.pop();
    }
}
```

Compiler says that `pop()` in `MinStack` needs return type of `Node`. Isn't that implemented by `super.pop()`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You are not returning it:

```
return super.pop();
```

I assume you are coming from a more functional background; in Java, putting something at the end of the function/method does not mean the function/method returns the value.